# Spring isn't loading CSS and gives a 404 when the page is loaded

Tags: java, css, spring

I'm running a Spring (not Boot) web app and it's finding my JSP views properly, but my CSS isn't being found for some reason. To be clear, the page is loading with the necessary elements, but any CSS styling from classes in my `.css` files is not being applied. The structure for the CSS file I'm trying to use is `src/main/resources/css/style.css`.

Below is the relevant code for my `AppConfig` class:

```
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/css/");
    }
    ...
}
```

And the JSP header:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css"/>
```

I've already checked some other questions asking after this issue and have had no luck. Several of them advised checking the config file for Spring Security to ensure that permission is granted for all requests using the resource file but based on what I can see, it shouldn't be prohibiting the CSS from being loaded:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);

        return authenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have the `css` directory in your app (context) directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-Spring Boot project your `css` folder should be not in `src/main/resources` but in `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: This completely solved it. Thank you so much. Out of curiosity, why would my ResourceHandler not point to my resources directory as a valid part of the path class? I was under the impression that adding that handler was with the aim of including Resources on Spring's list of classpath directories.

Comment: Then don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Regarding your question, that's not correct. If you don't include the ResourceHandler, then only your `@RequestMapping` (or `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` etc) endpoints will work. Spring MVC doesn't expose the files from `src/main/webapp` by default.

Comment: The word Resource in `ResourceHandler` doesn't refer to Maven resources folder. It refers to the web resources that are to be served by HTTP via fixed URLs.

Comment: I think I understand. So the function of the `ResourceHandler` here is to tell Spring that it should check `<classpath>/css/**` for resources and since the webapp folder is part of the classpath, it's able to find my CSS folder?

Comment: @iducam The webapp folder is not part of the classpath. Did you read my answer below, which provides details on `ResourceHandlerRegistry`? It looks like you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell spring security to ignore css files by overriding this method in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**").anyRequest();
 }
```

Comment: I just tried overriding the method as you described, but the page still wont load my CSS and issues a 404 to the Inspector regarding the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

The configuration that you posted in your question:

```java
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/css/");
    }
    ...
}
```

tells Spring MVC to serve `/css/style.css` from the `css` directory in your context directory. If it doesn't exist, you get a 404.

If you want to serve the file from the classpath (which is what your question seems to imply), then you should do this instead:

```java
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/css/");
    }
    ...
}
```

See the documentation of [`ResourceHandlerRegistry`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html) for more details.